# Регулярное выражение не соответствующие ничему

Tags: регулярные-выражения, pcre

Имеется корпоративное файловое хранилище примерно такой структуры: `Группа/Проект/Состояние/Файл`

Есть внутренняя утилиту для поиска и обработки файлов с возможностью указывать условие поиска.

Глубина вложенности не постоянная, например у некоторых групп есть подгруппы, у некоторых проектов есть подпроекты, а у некоторых проектов с небольшим количеством файлов нет подкаталогов Состояние, оно отражено в имени файла. Структуру менять нельзя.

В 99% случае условие поиска имеет следующий вид: Все файлы из групп Группа1 и Группа2, кроме состояний Состояние1 и Состояние2

Поэтому в утилите отсев сделан в виде двух регулярок:

1. Пропускать файлы, не соответствующие первой - отсев по группе/подгруппе/проекту
2. Пропускать файлы, соответствующие второй - отсев по состоянию

Появилась необходимость для некоторых проектов обрабатывать все состояния, то есть вторая регулярка не должна срабатывать.

Если регулярку не заполнять, программа не начинает обработку.

**Собственно вопрос**: Какому перл-совместимому (PCRE) регулярному выражению не будет соответствовать ни одно имя файл?

PS файловое хранилище на linux, поэтому в имен файла могут быть любые символы

Comment: На просьбу исправить программу автор ответил, что там ошибка в используемой библиотеке и ближайшее дни у него не будет времени исправить.

Comment: Сделать поиск символа, запрещенного для именования файлов и директорий. Или поиск пустой строки.

Comment: @Alpensin, в последней строке я ж написал, что недопустимых символов нет, т.к.это Linux. А пустая строка - это как? Не соображу

Comment: Сори, не заметил. Пустая строка - ^$ .

Comment: Выражение, которое никогда не найдет совпадения, это `(?!)`. Или `$a`, `a^`, `(?=a)x` и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Регулярные выражения, которые никогда не найдут совпадения ни в одной строке:

- `x^` - Буква `x`, за которой следует начало строки (универсальный шаблон)
- `$x` - Конец строки, после которого должна идти буква `x` (универсальный шаблон)
- `x\ba` - Буква `x`, за которой должна быть граница слова и буква `a` (требуется поддержка границ слова, в PostgreSQL это `\y`)
- `\b\B`/`\B\b` - Позиция, которая должна быть одновременно и границей слова и противположной позицией (требуется поддержка границ слова, в PostgreSQL, Tcl, TRE это `\m` и `\M`)
- `x++x` - После одной и более `x` должна быть ещё одна буква `x` (без бэктрекинга) (требуется  поддержка сверхжадных кванитификаторов)
- `(?>x+)x` - То же, что и `x++x`
- `(?!)` - Сразу после текущей позиции не должно быть ничего (требуется поддержка блоков предварительного просмотра)
- `(?=a)x` - Сразу после текущей позиции должна быть `a` **И** `x` (требуется поддержка блоков предварительного просмотра)
- `(?!a)a` - Сразу после текущей позиции не должно быть `a`, но должна быть `a` (требуется поддержка блоков предварительного просмотра)
- `(*FAIL)` - То же, что и `(?!)` (только PCRE)
- `(*F)` - То же, что и `(*FAIL)`.